# Show that $End_{\mathbb{K}}(\mathbb{V})$ is Dedekind finite ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A ring $R$ is said to be *Dedekind finite* if $ab=1 \Rightarrow ba=1$. Let $\mathbb{V}$ a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-vector space, show that $End_{\mathbb{K}}(\mathbb{V})$ is Dedekind finite ring.

Comment: Thoughts, ideas, effort? What have you tried?

Comment: I made a finite basis of V, two functions $f,g \in End_{\mathbb{K}}(\mathbb{V})$ and suppose that $f(g(x))=x$ for all $x \in V$. I tried to do the math but it came to nothing, do not know another way to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ is $n$-dimensional, $\operatorname{End}_{\Bbb K}(V)$ is identified with the ring $M_n(\Bbb K)$ of $n\times n$ matrices over $\Bbb K$, via the identification $M_n(\Bbb K) \to \operatorname{End}_K(V)$, $A \mapsto f_A : x\to Ax$. So it suffices to show $M_n(\Bbb K)$ is a Dedekind finite ring. Take $A, B \in M_n(\Bbb K)$ with $AB = I$. Then $BA = I$ if and only if $A$ is invertible. Now if $A$ is not invertible, then there is a sequence $E_1,\ldots, E_r$ of elementary matrices such that $E_1E_2\ldots E_r A$ has a row of zeros. Then $E_1E_2\cdots E_r AB$ has a row of zeros, i.e., $E_1E_2\ldots E_r$ has a row of zeros. This cannot happen since $E_1E_2\cdots E_r$ is invertible. Hence $A$ is invertible and $BA = I$.

Comment: Why $E_1E_2 ...E_r$ is invertible?

Comment: It's because each $E_i$ is invertible.

Comment: Also @Croos, the finite product of invertible matrices is invertible.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I could not see why each matrix $E_i$ is invertible. I can choose a sequence of invertible matrices such that this will occur? Would that be?

Comment: @Croos elementary matrices are invertible.

Comment: Course, are elementary matrices. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Relate the relations $ab=1$ and $ba=1$ to injectivity and surjectivity.